# How to repeat a string while using a floating point number as multiplier

Tags: php, floating-point, str-replace

I recently had to repeat a string n-times to match the length of another string. The problem was that my multiplier was a floating point number and str_repeat only accepts integer.

To be more precisely I had a string of all lowercase and uppercase letters of the alphabet (strlen: 52) and had to match the length of a string containing numbers from 0-9 (strlen: 10) against it.

Since I did some research before and could not find the answer I was looking for I am going to share my function Q&A-style.

Answer (score 2):

To multiply a string n-times with a floating point number as multiplier you need to do some basic maths. Here is what I came up with:

```
function str_repeat_float($str, $m){
    $f = floor($m);
    $d = $m - $f;
    $l = strlen($str);
    $p = floor($d * $l);
    $r_str = str_repeat($str, $f);
    $s_str = substr($str, 0, $p);
    return $r_str.$s_str;
}
echo str_repeat_float('1234567890', 5.2);
// 1234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012
```